# windows 2012 new installation and EVENT ID 407 408

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-vsphere

i just bought server from reliablesite.net which i think its not reliable at all.

and installed new windows server 2012 R2 on one of vps..i set an ip address and got remote to server and installed dns server

after installing dns server and one reboot i keep getting this event id 407 408 404 and sometimes no ping to server at all and i should reboot again to get ping from server

so i asked Data center they just want to over charge us for more 50 $ and i am not going to pay them more because i know how to config server atleast in past servers that i had(arround 30 server that i had and no similar issue)
so called support they just gave me these 2 links which i have done about maybe 4 times and checked everything...and i even tryed new installation!!

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735852(v=ws.10).aspx
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279678

in dns>interfaces i checked  only one ip for my dns server which is static ip for server

in vmware section > Configuration > Networking Adaptor i can see vmnic 1 and vmnic 0 
vmnic0 1000 FULL Vswitch 0
vmnic1 down

i just built 1 network card for this vps..and put network card on E1000 type

so what do you think guys...where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install VMware tool on the server and then change the adaptor to be VMXNET3 to check if the problem still exist or not.

Answer (score -1):

From [www.eventid.net - event id 408 from DNS](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-408-source-DNS-eventno-778-phase-1.htm%20%22Event%20id%20408), there are several issues with VMWare virtual servers using E1000. Maybe this is the case here?